# How to call an activity in another project?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi  I am new to android and I have created 2 projects.

Now I want to call an activity in the second project from the first project upon a button click.

The 1st project only handles login screen and when I click on the login button I need to call an activity which is present in the second project.

I searched the net but didn't find any tutorials which I understood properly.

Hi I found the following error.

```
01-30 08:36:47.230: E/dalvikvm(3408): Could not find class 'com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity', referenced from method org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:69)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.LoginActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-30 08:36:52.587: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):     ... 3 more
```

I have declared the manifest as this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.fluturasymphony.recommendation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CategoryWiseSalesChartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductWiseSalesChartActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/home_screen" android:name=".HomeActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/store_screen" android:name=".StoreActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/store_list_screen" android:name=".StoreListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/location_screen" android:name=".StoreMapActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/recommended_products_list_screen" android:name=".RecommendedProductsListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/category_wise_sales_screen" android:name=".CategoryWiseSalesActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/product_wise_sales_screen" android:name=".ProductWiseSalesActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
                <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    </application>



</manifest>
```

And I am calling the activity in the 2nd class like this.

```
Intent loginintent = new Intent("com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity");
                        startActivity(loginintent);
```

Is this right??

Comment: Go through "Remote Service process"  Concept.

Comment: +1 for everyone who helped me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Android you can handle this by making the project [Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) and then Define it in the manifest file and call it in what ever manner you want

for an explanation i did this as per my requirement 
the activity you want to call on Button click Define it in  the Manifest with its full package name and then when you call it on button click the activity of the new project will trigger 
the sample to do this is following 
in the `manifest` file of your 1st project define some thing like this

```
<activity 
        android:name="packagefull.activityname"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    </activity>
```

in the package name  define the full path of the the activity you want to call and after the package name give the name of the activity 
hope this will work for you as this worked perfect for me

Comment: Thank you ill check it and get back to you. do you have any more resources to explain this?

Comment: I did the same but got the No Activity Found Exception. Do you know the reason please?

Comment: Can anybody tell me this method is valid now? I tried hours and still no hope. Thank you

Comment: For anyone struggling...make sure to read and implement the "Library" Link in the answer.

Comment: Struggled alot to find this solution. How can i Vote more than one?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("app package name", "app launch activity's classname"));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a good way for developing any application. But still if you want to achieve this , you will have to declare an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) for the target activity in that application's Manifest file and use it as implicit intent from your login activity.

Inside project A's Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.android.TargetActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.someone.wants.to.call.me"></action>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Inside project B's Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.someone.wants.to.call.me");
         startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in the map project's AndroidManifest file add your custom intent filter

   ```
    <!-- add custom action -->
    <activity android:name="MapActivity"
               android:label="@string/mapLabel"
           >
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.example.map.show" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
   ```
2. from the login button call this activity like this:

Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.map.show");
    startActivity(intent);

Answer (score -1):

You should be using one project for each application. If you want to split up your login from the rest of your application you could use different packages. Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean by "project"?

Comment: I have the code for login in a separate project and the code for map display in a separate project and when I click on the login button it should go to the second project and display the map and after displaying when the user clicks a button it should come back to the main project where I have written the code for login screen and it need to display the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Can you give a reason for having them in separate projects? From what I understand it seems like you have one activity for your login and one activity for your map display... If that's true you shouldn't need 2 projects unless your login and map display are overly sophisticated?

Comment: Well the number of classes in the first project is more and I didn't want to add this also to it now only it looks a bit clustered and it becomes difficult to keep track of things so I have 2 projects.