# Xamarin run activity from other project in same solution

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a xamarin solution with two android projects. I would like to run android activity in project1 from project2. I ‘ve seen threads related to this topic (like [How to call an activity in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596999/how-to-call-an-activity-in-another-project)
[Call activity from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005223/call-activity-from-another-project)) and tried many suggested solutions but In the end I always get „Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'Unable to find explicit activity class {companyname.project2/companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?'” error. Is this possible in xamarin if yes how? Am I doing something wrong? Here is my source code:

Project1:

```
namespace BigAppManager {

    [Activity (MainLauncher = true, Name = "com.companyname.bigappmanager.MainActivity", Label = " Logowanie", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize, NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxActivity<MainActivityViewModel> {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init (this, savedInstanceState);
            
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button);

            button.Click += ClickButton;
        }

        private void ClickButton (object sender, EventArgs e) {
  
            //Intent intent = new Intent("companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView");
            //StartActivity(intent);
            Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionMain);
            intent.AddCategory (Intent.CategoryLauncher);
            // intent.SetClassName("companyname.project2", "companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView");
            intent.SetComponent (new ComponentName ("companyname.project2", "companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView"));
            StartActivity (intent);

        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults) {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Project2:

```
[Activity(Name = "companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView", Label = " Logowanie", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize, NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance)]
    public class LoginView : MvxActivity<LoginViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginView);

        }
    }
```

Project 2 android manifest intent filter:

```
<activity android:name="companyname.project2.Droid.View.LoginView">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="companyname.project2.View.LoginView"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Manifests are merged by default. So if you look at the resulting AndroidManifest.xml in obj/Debug/android when building, you will probably notice that the LoginView entry is missing.

You can try adding the following NuGet package to your App project and see if that will merge the manifests: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.ManifestMerger/1.0.0-preview03

Otherwise, you will need to add the same entry manually in your Apps manifest for the LoginView.

EDIT:

Make sure you use the correct intent. This works fine for me:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginView));
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it doesnt seem to work. Still getting the same error. I've tried adding mentioned nuget package to to first, second and both projects. Tried adding manually same intent filter to first project. In both AndroidManifest.xml located in obj/Debug/android added manually activities are visible.

Comment: After few tries i've made it work. It seems that other app must be installed to start activity from other project. I've needed to start activity from other project without installation so I made my second project as library. Thank you for help i will mark It as accepted answer.